# change username without changing the old repository address ?

Tags: git, bitbucket

I want to change my bitbucket username. Bitbucket allow me to change the username as many time i want to change but with a warning

> Renaming this account will change the URLs of 3 repository

I am working with a team.changing the name create problem for others team members or not ?. and is their any alternate to solve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no alternative to this. Your repositories are located at `bitbucket.org/<username>/<repositoryname>`. Changing the username obviously changes the URL for each repository.

If you want to keep the old URLs, you cannot rename your account.

Having new repository URLs shouldn’t be a too difficult problem though, and you can easily communicate this in your team. The fix is rather simple too:

```
git remote set-url origin git@bitbucket.org/<newusername>/<repositoryname>
```

Comment: ok thanks, if i change my remote url what about my logs , commit history ?

Comment: That all stays the same. Nothing in your repository cares about where a remote repository is located, or even where a commit came from; once you fetched a change, it’s in your repository just like any local commit.